# Is there any formula to find the sum of a series like $ (n/16)^{3/4}+(n/16^2)^{3/4}+(n/16^3)^{3/4} \cdots $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering if there is any way to find the sum of series like this either finite(upto some n and we do not know the value of n) or infinite.

$$\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^{3/4}+\left(\frac{n}{16^2}\right)^{3/4}+\left(\frac{n}{16^3}\right)^{3/4}+\ldots$$

Comment: You want to calculate $$S = n^{\frac{3}{4}}\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{16^{\frac{3i}{4}}}\text{?}$$ Please take a look at the geometric series...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^{3/4}+\left(\frac{n}{16^2}\right)^{3/4}+\left(\frac{n}{16^3}\right)^{3/4}+\ldots{=n^{3\over 4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over 16^{3k\over 4}}\\=n^{3\over 4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over 2^{3k}}\\=n^{3\over 4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over 8^{k}}=\\=n^{3\over 4}{{1\over 8}\over 1-{1\over 8}}\\={1\over 7}n^{3\over 4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it in summation notation to see that$$S=n^{3/4}\sum\limits_{k\geq1}16^{-3k/4}$$Now use the formula for the infinite geometric sequence for $|r|<1$

$$\sum\limits_{n\geq1}r^n=\frac r{1-r}$$This can be proven by expanding out the infinite sum and noting how$$\begin{align*}A & =r+r^2+r^3+\cdots\\ Ar & =\phantom{r+}\space\space r^2+r^3+\cdots\end{align*}$$Now subtract and isolate $A$. In this case, $r=16^{-3/4}$ and simplifying, the answer turns out to be$$S\color{blue}{=\frac {n^{3/4}}{7}}$$